# Paypal - How to split a payment given user credit card information

Tags: .net, paypal, paypal-sandbox, payment

I have an application that receives a payment from a user, say 100 dollars, then 20 go to me and 80 to a service provider in my site.

I get the user's credit card information and perform the 20 dollars payment to my account perfectly, but the problem is how to send the remaining 80 dollars to the service provider.

So far, I can create a payment by using PayPal .NET SDK (DirectPayment API) given the user's credit card and personal information just fine, for this I have to set my clientId and clientSecret.

I can't find a way to split the payment without requiring the user to be logged in his PayPal account. I don't want the user to be logged into PayPal since we only accept direct credit card payments.

PayPal provides different way to split payments but they require redirecting the customer to PayPal for authorization. For example in the Adaptive Payments API they provide: [Parallel Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-parallelPayment-curl-etc/), [Chained Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicChainedPayment-curl-etc/)

At first, I thought I could perform a second transaction similar to the first one but the problem is that I would also require my users service providers to send me their clientId and clientSecret which is not a good idea.

So how can I split a payment without requiring the user to be logged in paypal?

Comment: To do it with direct credit cards you would need to make 2 separate API requests.  Then buyer would see 2 separate transactions on their statement, though, and you would have to setup permissions to make the DDP call on behalf of the 3rd party account.  You could let the full 100 come to you and then push it out to the 3rd party account, but then you would be liable for any credit card disputes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Andrew. I have changed my mind about direct credit cards, I will be using DirectPayment which require the user to be authenticated in PayPal.